# Question about roots in polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Is it possible for a polynomial of degree higher than or equal to 5 having no complex and real root at all?

Comment: check out this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Comment: No this is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

No -- every polynomial of positive degree with coefficients in $\mathbb C$ has at least one root in $\mathbb C$.

This is the [**Fundamental Theorem of Algebra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

When the degree is $5$ or more, the roots cannot necessarily be *expressed with $\sqrt[n]{\vphantom X\cdots}$ signs* (in combination with other arithmetic operations, starting from the coefficients), but they'll be out there somewhere nevertheless.